Подсчет вхождений по ключевым словам
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427467/mysql-count-instances-of-substring-then-order-by
Нашел функцию, которая подсчитывает количество вхождений. Если не ошибаюсь, ищет по одному ключу...
Толком не разбираюсь, быть может кто сможет доработать ее. Сделать так, чтобы подсчитывала количество вхождений по нескольким ключевым словам? Возможно ошибаюсь, но в ней вроде есть привязка по регистру. Возможно и ее убрать?
DELIMITER //
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `subStringCount`//
    CREATE FUNCTION `subStringCount` (sequence VARCHAR(1000), word VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT(4)
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE counter SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE word_length SMALLINT UNSIGNED;
    
        SET word_length = CHAR_LENGTH(word);
    
        WHILE (INSTR(sequence,word) != 0) DO
            SET counter = counter+1;
            SET sequence = SUBSTR(sequence, INSTR(sequence,word)+word_length);
        END WHILE; 
    
        RETURN counter;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;

